# how to limit .draggable to a scaled div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I already found several helpful examples concerning this topic, but now I am not able to adapt the different suggestions for my needs. My problem is as follows:

I have a scaled down (40% of actual size) div element with an image in it. On top of it, you select elements via mouse click an move them around. Later, you can export the image in its original size. This is working just fine.

I already found the following code here on SO, which helped with the proper scaling of the mouse movement:

```
var click = {x:0, y:0};

    $('.spieler').draggable({           

        containment: "#test",

        start: function(event, ui) {
            click.x = event.clientX;
            click.y = event.clientY;
        },

        drag: function(event, ui) {
            // This is the parameter for scale()
            var zoom = 0.4;  //already adjusted for my needs
            var original = ui.originalPosition;

            // jQuery will simply use the same object we alter here
            ui.position = {
            left: (event.clientX - click.x + original.left) / zoom,
            top:  (event.clientY - click.y + original.top ) / zoom,
            };

    }

});
```

But now I need to limit the draggable area to the area of the scaled div.

```
containment: "#test",
```

Did not work. Do you have any tips for me on how to limit the area to this specific element instead of the whole visible screen? A possible solution seems to be: http://jsfiddle.net/enHmy/1/
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The code in the drag function is executing after the internal jQuery UI code that limits the position to the containment object. So, you'll have to run some additional code to enforce containment. This should work:

```
var click = {x:0, y:0};

$('.spieler').draggable({           

    containment: "#test",

    start: function(event, ui) {
        click.x = event.clientX;
        click.y = event.clientY;
    },

    drag: function(event, ui) {
        // This is the parameter for scale()
        var zoom = 0.4;  //already adjusted for my needs
        var original = ui.originalPosition;
        var widget = $(this).data('ui-draggable');
        var containment = widget.containment;
        var left = event.clientX - click.x + original.left;
        var top = event.clientY - click.y + original.top ;

        // Enforce containment
        if ( left < containment[ 0 ]) left = containment[ 0 ];
        if ( top < containment[ 1 ]) top = containment[ 1 ];
        if ( left > containment[ 2 ]) left = containment[ 2 ];
        if ( top > containment[ 3 ]) top = containment[ 3 ];

        // jQuery will simply use the same object we alter here
        ui.position = {
            left: left / zoom,
            top:  top / zoom,
        };

    }
});
```

This will only work when containment is set to a CSS selector. If you are using an array of values for containment, the `containment` variables will be relative to the document instead of the offset parent. You'd have to add additional code that would change the `containment` variable to remove the offset parent position or just set a completely new `containment` variable within the `drag` function that has positions relative to the offset parent.